# Как передать данные в представления более гибко

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Как мне сделать более гибко передачу данных в представление.
В данном примере передаю данные в обратном порядке, и выводится - все хорошо. Но, как мне передать если еще надо на этой же странице вывести эти данные, только в обратном порядке или к примеру последних 5 записей. 
 
Controller:

```
 List<ProductViewModel> model = new List<ProductViewModel>();


        List<ProductViewModel> model = new List<ProductViewModel>();
                _context.Products
                            .OrderBy(a => a.Position)
                            .ToList()
                             .ForEach(a => {
                           ProductViewModel listingProduct = new ProductViewModel
                                {
                                    Name = a.Name,
                                    Price = a.Price,
                                    PreviousPrice = a.PreviousPrice,
                                    Position = a.Position,
                                    Attached = a.Attached,
                                };
                                model.Add(listingProduct);
                            });
                        return View(model);
```

View:

```
@using Ad.ViewModels
@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>
  @foreach (var product in Model)
  {
    <p>@product.Price</p>
    ......
    }
```

То как я понимаю, обязательно для вывода данных нужно в `ViewModel` заносить данные. А через ViewBag или ViewData это делать явно не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представление всегда может вывести коллекцию в нужном порядке или ее часть:

```
@using Ad.ViewModels
@model List<ProductViewModel>

<h3>Items as they come:</h3>
  @foreach (var product in Model)
  {
    <p>@product.Price</p>
    ......
  }

<h3>Items in reversed order:</h3>
  @for (int i = Model.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    <p>@Model[i].Price</p>
    ......
  }

<h3>Last five items:</h3>
  @for (int i = Math.Max(0, Model.Count - 5); i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    <p>@Model[i].Price</p>
    ......
  }
```

С другой стороны, следует ответить на вопрос - кому известно про такие вещи как "в обратном порядке" и "последние пять элементов". Это информация наверняка доступна в контроллере. Перед вызовом `View(model);` контроллер может скомпоновать/изменить список, как это требуется.

Comment: А если например, надо будет данные другой модели вывести. То чуть не нравится подход, что в представления логика выносится

Comment: @Andrey Данные *другой* модели будет выводить *другое* представление.

Comment: Выдает после @Model[i].Name
`cannot apply indexing  with [] to an expression of type IEnumerable`. 
Не подскажешь, как исправить?

Comment: @Andrey Вы, видимо, не обратили внимания, на вторую строчку в коде ответа: `@model List<ProductViewModel>`

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @Andrey Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Хотел бы еще услышать ответы на эту тему, не будет - обязательно поставлю)