# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument в представление razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

```
var model = _context.Services
            .Include(b => b.ServiceDetail)
            .ThenInclude(b=>b.Category)
            .ToList();
   return View(model);
```

В asp.net core передал вот эту модель в view.Связи реализовал как мне надо.
Так вот у меня есть в модели поле типа `bool` "Attached".
Мне нужно вывести значения, где `attached == true`, а в другой части представления где `attached == false.`
Пробывал вот так в представление:

```
@foreach(var sd in Model.Where(a => a.Attached == false))
{ ... }
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type.

Подскажите, как вообще можно решить это.
P.S знаю, что можно в контроллере добавить Where, но будет выводить тогда только с одним условием.

Update, примерные связи:
Модель ServiceDetail

```
public Service Service { get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }
```

Модель Service:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Url { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceDetail> ServiceDetail { get; set; }
```

Comment: А как у вас модель объявлена в этом представлении? В самом начале файла.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в представление никак не объявлял

Comment: Ну так надо объявить. Проблема исчезнет.

Comment: Ошибка связана с тем, что система просто не знает типа Вашей модели. Его всегда нужно объявлять в начале файла

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Какую именно модель объявлять? То как эту переданную объявить через model - не знаю

Comment: Да господи. Посмотрите тип того, что Вы отправили во View. И просто перепишите тип в начало файла

Comment: Если вы не указываете тип с помощью `@model MyType`, то модель интерпретируется как `dynamic` (а это ещё и чревато проблемами с производительностью). Так как метод `Where` неизвестен до выполнения, то непонятно, как интерпретировать лямбду: как делегат или как дерево выражений

Comment: `@model List<ProductViewModel>` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933860/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE

Comment: Всем спасибо, действительно помогло)